# How to get LastModifiedDate of Custom Field or Custom Label by Metadata API in Java?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, java

How to get LastModifiedDate of Custom **Field** or Custom **Label** by Metadata API in Java?

Edit: I found a link:

`https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm?search_text=LastModifiedDate`

and the text there:

`"Other standard fields aren't supported, including system fields (such as CreatedById or LastModifiedDate) and autonumber fields.Some standard picklist fields aren’t supported."`

...

So it seems, that my field `Memes__c.Flipping_Tables__c.LastModifiedDate` will not work.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation snippet you refer to is explaining a limitation on which standard fields on an object you can retrieve with the Metadata API. There's a difference between retrieving the metadata for the *standard field* `LastModifiedDate` and retrieving the last modified date *of some custom field*.

However, as far as I'm aware, neither the Metadata API's [`CustomField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) entity nor the Tooling API's [`EntityParticle`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entityparticle.htm) provides this information.

You can issue queries against the Setup Audit Trail to find a historical snapshot of this kind of change, although it's subject to the limitations of that feature (limited retention; query limitations; based on time rather than a per-field history). For example, you can do

```
SELECT Section, Display, Action, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate 
FROM SetupAuditTrail 
WHERE Action = 'createdCFCustom'
```

to get back a list of Custom Field creation events during the course of the Audit Trail's retention window. Unfortunately, the information is not structured all that well for machine parsing.